# JavaScript recursive function for date/time messages

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am working on an application that shows a nest of cells - which have different date/time properties. I have found the functionality here is working - but I am unsure how to improve the code below to turn it into a recursive function.

I was thinking of wrapping part of the loop into a function and using a callback at the point of digging deeper - but I didn't succeed

something like this as a poc

```
recursiveFunction = (startTime, endTime, unit1, unit2, callback) => {

                if (timeRan(startTime, unit1) < 0) {
                    return this.msgStartIn(startTime, unit1);
                }
                if (timeRemaining(endTime, unit1) < 0) {
                    return this.msgFinishedAgo(endTime, unit1);
                } else {


                    //ends today in 1 unit1
                    if (timeRemaining(endTime, unit1) === 0) {
                        if (timeRan(startTime, unit2) < 0) {
                            return this.msgStartIn(startTime, unit2);
                        }
                        if (timeRemaining(endTime, unit2) < 0) {
                            return this.msgFinishedAgo(endTime, unit2);
                        } else {

                             callback()

                        }
                    }
                    return this.msgRemaining(endTime, unit1);
                }
}
```

code below

---

```
msgStartIn = (startTime, unit) => {
    return (
        'Start in ' +
        Math.abs(timeRan(startTime, unit)) +
        ' ' + unit
    );
};

msgFinishedAgo = (endTime, unit) => {
    return (
        'Finished ' +
        Math.abs(timeRemaining(endTime, unit)) +
        ' ' + unit + ' ago'
    );
};

msgRemaining = (endTime, unit) => {
    return (
        this.toTitleCase(unit) + ' remaining ' +
        timeRemaining(endTime, unit)
    );
};


getCampaignProgress = (startTime, endTime) => {

            if (timeRan(startTime, 'days') < 0) {
                return this.msgStartIn(startTime, 'days');
            }
            if (timeRemaining(endTime, 'days') < 0) {
                return this.msgFinishedAgo(endTime, 'days');
            } else {


                //ends today in 1 day
                if (timeRemaining(endTime, 'days') === 0) {
                    if (timeRan(startTime, 'hours') < 0) {
                        return this.msgStartIn(startTime, 'hours');
                    }
                    if (timeRemaining(endTime, 'hours') < 0) {
                        return this.msgFinishedAgo(endTime, 'hours');
                    } else {

                        //ends today in 1 hour
                        if (timeRemaining(endTime, 'hours') === 0) {
                            if (timeRan(startTime, 'minutes') < 0) {
                                return this.msgStartIn(startTime, 'minutes');
                            }

                            if (timeRemaining(endTime, 'minutes') < 0) {
                                return this.msgFinishedAgo(endTime, 'minutes');
                            } else {

                                //ends today in 1 minute
                                if (timeRemaining(endTime, 'minutes') === 0) {
                                    if (timeRan(startTime, 'seconds') < 0) {
                                        return this.msgStartIn(startTime, 'seconds');
                                    }

                                    if (timeRemaining(endTime, 'seconds') < 0) {
                                        return this.msgFinishedAgo(endTime, 'seconds');
                                    } else {
                                        return this.msgRemaining(endTime, 'seconds');
                                    }
                                }
                                return this.msgRemaining(endTime, 'minutes');
                            }
                        }
                        return this.msgRemaining(endTime, 'hours');
                    }
                }
                return this.msgRemaining(endTime, 'days');
            }


};
```

---

solved - latest code fix

https://jsfiddle.net/6ohyrkqL/9/ -- added a progress indicator bar

Comment: Why do you want to "turn this into a recursive function"?

Comment: "I was thinking of wrapping part of the loop..." What loop?

Comment: So you think a loop is the approach to go? -- I thought of a recursive function - so it could call itself to go to a deeper level - if its a mix of a loop and a recursive function?

Comment: @Rob - I don't think these folks have an opinion, because the question is tough to understand.  Can you edit it to describe the inputs and outputs?  What's a nest of cells, what times should be assigned to them, etc

Comment: its just a div of blocks - that have different start/end dates -- so campaigns that are about to start in 1 day time, 2 hours time, finished 3 hours ago... 4 minutes remaining

Comment: That doesn't really answer the point danh asked.  The inputs and expected outputs to your function are really what would give us a handle on what you're trying to do.  We don't know what `timeRan` or `timeReamaining` do, have no idea what your `unit1` and `unit2` are.  It looks as though you're trying to display time in discrete units ("3 days" or "7 minutes") but beyond that I don't understand.

Comment: the inputs are startTime and endTime --- and the units represent if its days, hours, minutes or seconds -- e.g. days remaining, minutes remaining, ran for x days, ran for x minutes...

Comment: The problem is that you have things like "nest of cells" and code that we don't see or know what it's doing.  Looking again, I'm starting to guess the requirements.  I'm also not sure why you want to do this recursively, although of course it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly, something like the following certainly seems cleaner.

This accepts three parameters: the start and end times of your event and the current time.  They can be either `Date` objects or timestamps (like `Date.now`).  You can even mix or match if that's easier.  (That's because we are either comparing with `<` or subtracting, either of which will convert Dates to timestamps as necessary.)

```js
const messages = {
  notStarted: 'Start in {time} {units}',
  remaining: '{titleUnits} remaining: {time}',
  completed: 'Finished {time} {units} ago'
}

const periods = [
  {units: 'days',    titleUnits: 'Days',    ms: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 },
  {units: 'hours',   titleUnits: 'Hours',   ms: 1000 * 60 * 60 },
  {units: 'minutes', titleUnits: 'Minutes', ms: 1000 * 60 },
  {units: 'seconds', titleUnits: 'Seconds', ms: 1000 },
  {units: 'unknown', titleUnits: 'Unknown', ms: -1}
]

const getTime = (msg, start, finish) => {
  const {units, titleUnits, ms} = periods .find (({ms}) => finish - start > ms)
  const time = Math .round ((finish - start) / ms)
  return messages[msg] 
    .replace(/\{time\}/g, time)
    .replace(/\{units\}/g, units)
    .replace(/\{titleUnits\}/g, titleUnits)
}

const timeMessage = (begin, end, current) => 
  begin > end 
    ? 'uh oh -- do we need to throw here?'
  : current < begin
    ? getTime ('notStarted', current, begin)
  : current < end
    ? getTime ('remaining', current, end)
  : // else
    getTime ('completed', end, current)


console .log (timeMessage (new Date (2020, 1, 21, 18, 34, 52), new Date (2020, 1, 21, 20, 34, 52), new Date (2020, 1, 21, 24, 37, 21)))
console .log (timeMessage (new Date (2020, 1, 21, 18, 34, 52), new Date (2020, 1, 21, 24, 37, 21), new Date (2020, 1, 21, 24, 19, 52)))
console .log (timeMessage (new Date(2020, 1, 27, 24, 34, 52), new Date (2020, 1, 27, 24, 37, 21), new Date (2020, 1, 21, 18, 34, 52)))
```

It's more explicit, and I think makes it easier to change the text, which is concentrated in a fairly declarative fashion in the structures at the top.

The math to show the correct count is a guess.  I do a simple rounding.

There is probably some possible issues on boundaries.  What happens if now is exactly the end time, for instance?  Those can be fixed, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

If desired, all this could be compressed into a single function like this:

```js
const timeMessage = (begin, end, current) => {
  const {msg, start, finish} = begin > end 
    ? {msg: 'Uh oh -- do we need to throw here?', start: begin, finish: end}
  : current < begin
    ? {msg: 'Start in {time} {units}', start: current, finish: begin}
  : current < end
    ? {msg: '{titleUnits} remaining: {time}', start: current, finish: end}
  : // else
    {msg: 'Finished {time} {units} ago', start: end, finish: current}
  const {units, titleUnits, ms} = [
    {units: 'days',    titleUnits: 'Days',    ms: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 },
    {units: 'hours',   titleUnits: 'Hours',   ms: 1000 * 60 * 60 },
    {units: 'minutes', titleUnits: 'Minutes', ms: 1000 * 60 },
    {units: 'seconds', titleUnits: 'Seconds', ms: 1000 },
    {units: 'unknown', titleUnits: 'Unknown', ms: -1}
  ] .find (({ms}) => finish - start > ms)
  const time = Math .round ((finish - start) / ms)
  return msg 
    .replace(/\{time\}/g, time)
    .replace(/\{units\}/g, units)
    .replace(/\{titleUnits\}/g, titleUnits)
}
```

While this version has a smaller line count, I prefer the first one.  I think it's cleaner.

Comment: here is a jsfiddle of this - https://jsfiddle.net/6ohyrkqL/1/

Comment: without specifying current date - https://jsfiddle.net/6ohyrkqL/3/

Comment: @Rob: Note that the inline snippet above serves as a fine demonstration.  You don't need JSFiddle for this.  I would suggest snippets for most such code, using fiddles, jsbins, codepens, etc. only when there is simply too much code to reasonably fit in a snippet.

Comment: @Rob: Also note that your third Fiddle, which uses the current date rather than accepting a parameter, makes for a function that is much more difficult to test.  It's easy to write automated tests for pure functions.  But ones that give a different result depending upon when they're run are much more challenging.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6ohyrkqL/4/  -- I've added moment to the codebase

Comment: I am testing the jsfiddle against some timecodes I've currently used -- and where I had some bugs -- I think yours is more accurate - somewhere in my calculations it may not be correct in the time calculation ---- I need to expand this code/set of functions to also showcase a percentage bar ---- its part of a monolithic app

Comment: I think with the testing -- a date/time for the campaign would be set -- and it would probably do a string check against the block -- but for now this is a POC

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6ohyrkqL/6/  --- your code has fixed a bug I was having -- a campaign that is about to start in less than a day

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6ohyrkqL/9/ -- added a progress indicator bar

Comment: Thanks @Scott Sauyet - that solved all the issues I was having. I fell down some rabbit hole there.